# How do I modify a SSAS tabular model in Python?

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to make changes in a SSAS tabular model such as changing the datasources, among others.

I have already generated a script in python that is able to change the JSON that is capable of recognising, move and make changes. But I am looking for a specific package that could handle this as a proper model and not as a JSON object.

```
f = open('C:\\path\\to\\my\\model.bim', 'r')
jsondata = json.load(f)

result = nested_delete(
    document = jsondata,
    key = 'dataSources')

result['model']['dataSources'] = [
    {'name': "SQL Database",
    'connectionString': "xxxxxxxxxx"}
]

result = nested_update(
    document = result,
    key = 'dataSource',
    value = 'SQL Database'
) 

with open('C:\\path\\to\\my\\newmodel.bim', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(result, file, indent=2)
```

My idea is to do something like the python script above but treating the model as it is supposed because I am working with a huge model. I am open to codes in Python and Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving Tabular editor a shot? It is a lightweight SSAS Tabular IDE: https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor